# Predictions using a Keras Recurrent Neural Network - accuracy is always 1.0

Tags: python, neural-network

**TLDR:** How do I use a Keras RNN to predict the next value in a sequence?

---

I have a list of sequential values. I want to feed them into a RNN to *predict* the next value in the sequence.

```
[ 0.43589744  0.44230769  0.49358974 ...,  0.71153846  0.70833333 0.69230769]
```

I'm using Keras to do this and can get a network with a decreasing loss but the accuracy is consistently 1.0. This is wrong. `y_tests != model.predict(x_tests)`.

```
Epoch 0
1517/1517 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0726 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0636 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 1
1517/1517 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0720 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0629 - val_acc: 1.0000
...
```

Here's my network.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(1, 100))
model.add(Dense(100, 1, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer = "sgd")
```

I have tried a SimpleRNN, GRU and LSTM but have had no luck. Here is how the data is formatted.

```
# Current value
y_train = [[ 0.60576923] [ 0.64102564] [ 0.66025641] ..., [ 0.71153846] [ 0.70833333] [ 0.69230769]]

# Previous 10 values
x_train_10 = [
    [[ 0.65064103] [ 0.66346154] [ 0.66346154] ..., [ 0.72115385] [ 0.72435897] [ 0.71153846]] ...,
    [[ 0.66346154] [ 0.66346154] [ 0.67628205] ..., [ 0.72435897] [ 0.71153846] [ 0.70833333]]
]

# Previous value
x_train_1 = [[ 0.58333333] [ 0.60576923] [ 0.64102564] ...,  [ 0.72435897] [ 0.71153846] [ 0.70833333]]

# So here are the shapes...
y_train.shape    = (1895, 1)
x_train_10.shape = (1895, 10, 1)
x_train_1.shape  = (1895, 1)
```

Each element in `x_train_10` is a list of the previous 10 values. I formatted it like this to follow Keras's documentation that recurrent layers take inputs of shape `(nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim)`.

I have also tried using an `Embedding` layer with no luck. (This may be the wrong way to use it - I've only seen it used in classification not prediction).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1, 30))
model.add(LSTM(30, 100))
...
```

`pad_sequences` also did not work.

```
x_train_1 = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train_1, maxlen = None, dtype = "float32")
```

---

I want to get the RNN working with this simple data/architecture so I can use it for more complex problems later.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted a [similar question on the Keras Github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/724) page and got a good answer.

---

**lukedeo** said that `acc: 1.0000` means that both the true output and the predicted output are greater than 0.5 or vice versa. Instead, I should look at loss, or `mse`, to determine the accuracy of the model. This is because my network is a regression not a classifier/clusterer.

Root mean squared error is a good measure of accuracy. `accuracy_percent = 1 - np.sqrt(mse)`

---

**fchollet** (the Keras creator) elaborated by saying that "*accuracy is not relevant at all for a regression problem*."

When doing a classification problem, accuracy can be made relevant by setting `class_mode` to `'categorical'` or `'binary'` in `model.comple(...)` depending on the target (network output).

Answer (score 4):

Try RMSProp as optimiser

```
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer = 'rmsprop')
```