# Keras accuracy returning 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, sequential

So basically, I am working on this bullet optimization program. I wish to study how different ballistics parameters such as weight, length, and mass affect a ballistics coefficient. However, my training accuracy is 0, although there is loss and val_loss. I've read similar Stackoverflow posts regarding this, but none have helped me so far. Perhaps I just didn't do them right; I am referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/63513872/12349188

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df = pd.read_csv('Bullet Optimization\ShootForum Bullet DB_2.csv')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
dataset = df.values
X = dataset[:,0:12]
X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)

y = dataset[:,13]
y = np.asarray(y).astype(np.float32)

X_train, X_val_and_test, y_train, y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization

model = Sequential(
    [
        #2430 is the shape of X_train
        #BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum = 0.1),
        Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1,activation='softmax'),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

Did I do something wrong in my code? I know some python but I just kind of built upon the tutorials for my own purposes.

Comment: How many classes do you have? `Dense(1,activation='softmax') is wrong`. Or what are you trying to predict?

Comment: So given 13 parameters (such as dimensions, mass, density), I am trying to predict the ballistic coefficient (BC)

Comment: So their values are like 0.4, 0.8? If so, then this is not a classification.

Comment: What would this be considered then? Isn't it like regression, but on a multidimensional scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

First this line:

```
Dense(1,activation='softmax')
```

This line will cause the output `1` every time. So even if you are making classification, your accuracy would be 50% if you had 2 classes. `Softmax` outputs' sum will be equal to one. So using it with one neuron does not make sense.

You need to change your loss and metric as this is a **regression**.

```
loss='mse', metrics=['mse']
```

Also your output neuron should be linear which means does not need any activation function. It should be like:

```
Dense(1)
```

Comment: I've worked with pre-trained models, and it's high time I learn how to write my own sequential models! Thank you, I'll try it out; there's just so much to know!

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem after.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but how would I discern classification from regression? I kind of just guessed that this was regression since you're taking a bunch of parameters and fitting them to a single value, but what are some other tasks you would know of other than these two?

Comment: Classification is the problem of predicting a **discrete class label** output whereas regression is the problem of predicting a **continuous** quantity. [You can find more from here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-versus-regression-in-machine-learning/)

Comment: Well said, thank you. And since my current problem is regression, do you think there's a way I can visualize the line fitting as it happens, just as in playground.tensorflow.org ? I would think one uses matplotlib...

Comment: What do you mean by *as it happens*? If I understood right, you can use Tensorboard.